# Add onload to element without execution in Puppeteer

Tags: javascript, node.js, puppeteer

I'm writing a web scraper in Puppeteer. Once the page is ready, I've to rewrite the HTML and add an `onload` to some elements.

However, Puppeteer actually executes the `onload` event.

Original element: `<link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css"/>`

In Puppeteer, using `page.evaluate` method I run the following to the corresponding element:

```
elem.setAttribute('rel', 'preload');
elem.setAttribute('as', 'style');
elem.setAttribute('onload', "this.rel='stylesheet'");
```

Expected output: `<link rel="preload" as="style" href="style.css" onload="this.rel='stylesheet'" />`

Actual output: `<link rel="stylesheet" as="style" href="style.css" onload="this.rel='stylesheet'"/>`

Is there any way to prevent this `onload` in Puppeteer or somehow make it work?

The other solution would be doing this part in an HTML parser like [Cheerio](https://cheerio.js.org/).

Comment: Excuse me for asking but was is the purpose of what you're doing? (There may be another way of doing it) If this is a scraper why bother with stylesheets?

Comment: I'm building an optimizer where pages will be opened in Puppeteer, then several changes in html are done and capture final html. Another example would be adding 'defer' to all js files

Answer (score 0):

After opening the page, immediately set `page.setOfflineMode`. This will prevent loading that styles from preload and thus stops the `onload` event!

Code:

```js
await page.goto(url, {
    waitUntil: 'networkidle2',
});

await page.setOfflineMode(true);
```